# Facebook type friend search in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i want to make Facebook type friend search in my zend based application,in which data come from database and when user click on his searched friend he will go to his profile page.plese suggest me as i don't able to find good example on google.please someone help me and tell me step by step for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

checkout this tutorial it helps me lot do the same in my zend based application

Answer (score 0):

watched this: http://www.zendcasts.com/autocomplete-control-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/ Really great. It works perfectly.

at some stage you have to make some customize to call user profile on click event of list

Comment: i seen these video and made the uer search perfectly but the problem is that on click it put value in text box and no value in value field and no click works on it

Comment: but you have to add some custom function onclick event of jquery ui

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html  checkout this tutorial it helps me lot do the same in my zend based application